# Chrome text element readjusting

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui

If you pay close attention in chrome to the flipped text in this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-flower-101kx

You can see that the text `Test` readjusts after you flip a card.

Video: https://i.imgur.com/1Hb61dj.mp4

I believe it's something to do with the `Grid` because if you remove these lines it doesn't occur:

```js
xs={6}
sm={6}
md={6}
lg={6}
```

Does anyone know how to prevent it from readjusting, or the actual cause of it?

Comment: I can't see the issue. Can you make a short GIF describing the problem or elaborate further?

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 Added a video of it.